# how to access embeded data within Excel using Node JS

Tags: node.js, excel, pivot-table

We have an Excel file with a pivot table. When we double-click the totals row of that pivot table a new sheet is created with the source data.

How can I find this data programmatically using Node.js? I've looked at xlsx and node-xlsx but neither have documentation for this.

Comment: HI @patrickgamer, how you managed pivot table?

Comment: @A_J three file is sent to us by a third party. We don't create it

Comment: Yes, but how you did read those excel files, manged pivotal tables data?

Comment: I never solved this problem. If/when I do, I'll post an answer